# Maximize absolute value of complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I'm trying to solve exercise 9 in chapter 14 of Real & Complex Analysis of Walter Rudin:

> Suppose $g \in H(U), |\Re(g)|<1$ in $U$, and $g(0)=0$. Prove that
> $$|g(re^{it})|\le\frac2\pi\log\frac{1+r}{1-r}$$
> $U$ is the unit disc.

---

My thoughts:

Call $\Omega = \{x+iy:-1<x<1\}$. I constructed a one-to-one conformal mapping from $\Omega$ to $ U$:$$f(z) = -i\frac{\exp(\frac\pi2iz)-1}{\exp(\frac\pi2iz)+1}$$
I applied the Schwarz lemma to $f\circ g$ to get:$$\left| \frac{\exp(\frac\pi2ig(re^{it}))-1}{\exp(\frac\pi2ig(re^{it}))+1} \right| \le r$$

But no matter how I manipulate it, I cannot get $|g(re^{it})|$ out of it.

---

Another approach: Use the inverse of $f$:$$f^{-1}(z) = \frac2{\pi i}\log\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}$$

By using [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257032/if-f-g-u-rightarrow-omega-are-holomorphic-f0-g0-and-f-is-1-1onto) and the maximum modulus principle I get:
$$|g(re^{it})| \le \max_{t\in[0,2\pi]} |f^{-1}(re^{it})|$$

The right side reaches its maximum at $re^{3\pi i/2}$ per wolfram alpha, but I cannot do it via algebra or calculus (equations and derivatives too complicated).

---

I feel there is an easier way and I'm missing something. What is it?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using $\Omega$ as a strip? Look at a conformal mapping between the unit disc and the halfplane $\operatorname{Re}(z) < 1$ instead.

Comment: @mrf Thanks for your comment. I had a mistake in the problem statement. It's actually $|\Re(g)| < 1$ (with an absolute value).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Short version**
$$
\left|\log\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right|=2\left|\int_0^z \frac{d\zeta}{1-\zeta^2}\right| \le 
2 \int_0^{|z|} \frac{dt}{1-t^2} =\log\frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}
\tag1$$

**Long version**

The geometrically natural way to do this is in terms of the *hyperbolic (a.k.a. Poincaré) metric*, which Rudin does not introduce. It unifies various versions of the  Schwarz lemma   into a simple statement: "holomorphic maps are contractions in the hyperbolic metric". The hyperbolic metric on $U$ is 
$$
\rho_U(a,b)=\inf_\gamma \int_\gamma\frac{|d\gamma|}{1-|\gamma|^2}
\tag2$$
where the infimum is taken over all curves connecting $a$ to $b$. In this metric every point $z\in U$ with $|z|=r$ is at distance
$$\rho_U(z,0)=\int_0^r \frac{1}{1-r^2}\,dr=\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1+r}{1-r}
\tag3$$ from the origin. The hyperbolic distance between $g(z)$  and $g(0)=0$ in the domain $\Omega$ is no greater than $\rho_U(z,0)$. Using the conformal invariance of the hyperbolic metric, one finds that
$$
\rho_\Omega(a,b)=\inf_\gamma \int_\gamma \frac{\pi}{4}\frac{|d\gamma|}{\cos ( (\pi/2) \operatorname{Re}\gamma)}
\tag4$$ 
This is not as easy to calculate, but since the determinant is at most $1$, we have  $\rho_\Omega(a,b)\ge \frac{\pi}{4}|a-b|$. Conclusion: 
$$
|g(z)-g(0)|\le \frac{4}{\pi}\rho_\Omega(g(z),g(0))\le \frac{4}{\pi}\rho_U(z,0) = \frac{2}{\pi} \log\frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}
\tag5$$

Comment: Great answer. The hyperbolic metric section is fascinating. Ahlfors doesn't cover it either. What should I study to learn more about it?

Comment: @PeterM Try Chapters 2 and 3 of *Teichmüller theory* by John Hubbard. Chapter 1 may be intimidating, but can be skipped at first reading.

Comment: Fantastic. Insightful. Thank you.