# The bound of a log function

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

It looks like we can control $\log\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ by $\log\frac{1+r}{1-r}$ if $|z|=r<1$ where the logarithm is defined on the branch obtained by deleting the negative imaginary axis.

I tried to prove it but it's not so easy for me.

Somebody can help me to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximize absolute value of complex logarithm](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319407/maximize-absolute-value-of-complex-logarithm)

Comment: (that question has other things going on at first, but at the end it boils down to the estimate $\left|\log \frac{1+z}{1-z}\right|\le \log\frac{1+r}{1-r}$, which is proved in the answer.)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that my attempt to mark this question as a duplicate failed, I copy the answer from [the other thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/320169/85506): 
$$\left|\log\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right|=2\left|\int_0^z \frac{d\zeta}{1-\zeta^2}\right| \le 
2 \int_0^{|z|} \frac{dt}{1-t^2} =\log\frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}$$