# Proving $|f'(z)|\leq\frac{\text{Re}(f(z))}{\text{Re}(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Studying for a preliminary exam, I came across the following question:

> Let $D = \{z \in \Bbb C : \text{Re}( z )> 0\}$ and $f : D \to D $ be a holomorphic function. Prove that $$|f'(z)|\leq\frac{\text{Re}(f(z))}{\text{Re}(z)}\quad \text{for all }z\in D.$$

I thought the best way might be to use the fact that harmonic functions satisfy the maximum modulus principle, too, along with the limit definition of the derivative, but I wasn't able to get it worked out. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: This is a part of Schwarz-Pick theorem (the half-plane case); see e.g. Wikipedia (there you'll find a proof and some context)

Comment: The outline of a possible proof can be found here: http://anhngq.wordpress.com/2009/12/17/schwarzs-lemma-schwarz-pick-theorem-and-some-applications-involving-inequalities/ ,too.

Answer (score 1):

Let's put this into wider context.

**Fact 1**. If $D$ is a simply connected domain and  $f:D\to D$ is a holomorphic map with fixed point $a$, then   $|f'(a)|\le 1$.

*Proof*: apply the Schwarz lemma to $g^{-1}\circ f\circ g$ where $g$ maps the unit disk onto $D$ so that $g(0)=a$. $\quad \Box$

*Remark*: one can drop "simply connected" in Fact 1, but then the proof requires more    tools.

To apply Fact 1 here, fix $a\in D$ and consider 
 $g=\phi\circ f$ where $\phi$ is an automorphism $\phi$ of $D$ that sends $f(a)$ back to $a$. Since $|g'(a)|\le 1$, it follows that $|f'(a)|\le |\phi'(f(a))|^{-1}$.

Notice that $D$ can still be any simply connected domain above. Its shape comes into play only when we construct  $\phi$. Which for the right half-plane turns out to be
$$\phi(z)=\frac{\operatorname{Re}a}{\operatorname{Re}f(a)}\, (z-\operatorname{Im}f(a)) +i   \operatorname{Im}a $$

Comment: For an even wider context, see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/320169/